# Delegate launched with .BeginInvoke keeps throwing ThreadAbortExceptions?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous, begininvoke

Good morning

I have a block of code that is being run from a WCF service method. The intent is to execute an asynchronous process which will allow the original WCF service method to return a result without waiting for the process to run.

```
    public delegate void DoItAsync();
    public static void TriggerDocSubmissions()
    {
        var docSubmissionClient = new Services.DocumentSubmitter();
        try
        {
            var myAction = new DoItAsync(docSubmissionClient.DoWork);
            myAction.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.LogException(ex);
        }
    }
```

The code within the DoWork method shown above keeps throwing ThreadAbortExceptions. I understand that the thread being summoned to execute 'DoWork' to is a pooled thread, and that if anything aborts that thread then it will be perceived as a ThreadAbortException from the process running on that thread.

I do not need to know the result of the execution of the DoWork method because it updates the database with it's outcome.

In some cases, I'm seeing ThreadAbortExceptions very quickly after beginning execution of DoWork (milliseconds), sometimes it takes a longer time (20-30) seconds, sometimes it works without any issue?

How can I affect/better understand the ThreadAbortExceptions and their origin? Why does it happen sometimes and not other times?

I've looked up more information about the [BeginInvoke pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/calling-synchronous-methods-asynchronously), and can't find any information about how to manage/influence ThreadAbortExceptions.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you examined the `ThreadAbortedException`'s `ExceptionState` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadabortexception.exceptionstate)?

Comment: Just a note: `Delegate.BeginAsync` is basically deprecated, and throws an exception in .NET Core. Much better to use an explicit `Task.Run` or similar

Comment: @PeterCsala - the exception state property is not serialized when I log the exception?

Comment: @Todd It depends on what logger do you use. If this exception happens quite often then check the related log files.

Comment: ThreadAbortException is an exception that is thrown when the Abort method is called. Is there an Abort method in the DoWork method? If you want to call WCF service asynchronously, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-call-wcf-service-operations-asynchronously?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @DingPeng - there is definitely no Abort method in the DoWork method. I know there are multiple ways to do work asynchronously. Are you saying there is something inherent in the use of BeginInvoke - that is resulting in these sporadic ThreadAbortExceptions?

Comment: I think it may be caused by BeginInvoke. Will this exception occur if BeginInvoke is not used？

Comment: @DingPeng: I feel like it has to do with execution on a thread-pool process. I feel like something is killing the thread and my process is being terminated (by means of)/(by experiencing) a 'ThreadAbortException'.
I'm grateful for the idea - I will rig the code up to execute async and non-async and see if that affects the outcome. It will help me to understand this dynamic a little bit more.